# Changing the return value of a funtion is affecting elements that shouldn't be affected

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have this function defined and I pass it to `.apply()` so I can make it 'iterate' over all the elements of the column of a pandas dataframe

```
def mult(val):
    if not str(val).isnumeric():
        return val
    val *= 1000000
    return val
```

Like this:

```
df['Column_Name'] = df['Column_Name'].apply(mult)
```

---

When the function is defined as it is above, the output is:

- `321000000`

But when I define it this way:

```
def mult(val):
    if not str(val).isnumeric():
        return
    val *= 1000000
    return val
```

The output is different ( and incorrect ):

- `3.210000e+08`

---

Why is this happening? The value passed to get both outputs is `321`, which is an int so it shouldn't be affected by the return value of those values that aren't integers. Or at least that's what I think.
I'm sorta new to python so maybe this is something directly related to the language?

Oh, and I'm running this on Jupyter notebooks, maybe it has something to do with that? I really don't know

Comment: Does your dataframe have some rows where the column is not numeric? Or is that the only row?

Comment: I think it's because pandas pandas is selecting an appropriate dtype for the column based on all the values. When you set some of them to `None`, that causes it to use `float` for the numeric values.

Comment: @Barmar there are rows that don't have numeric values but those values aren't important

Comment: But in the first version, you're not changing the values of any of the other rows, so it doesn't need to choose a new dtype for the column.

Comment: @Barmar that makes sense, thank you!